# Kafka consumer not receiving messages when running the example on kafka.apache.org

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm quite new to Kafka and trying to run the consumer examples on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example ,but it doesn't receive any messages.

Here is the output in the eclipse console :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Shutting down Thread: 2
Shutting down Thread: 0
Shutting down Thread: 1
```

and below is my code for consumer

```
public class ConsumerDemo {
private final ConsumerConnector consumer; //why private final
private final String topic;
private ExecutorService executor;

public ConsumerDemo(String a_zookeeper,String a_groupId,String a_topic)
{
    consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig(a_zookeeper,a_groupId));
    this.topic=a_topic;
}

public void shutdown()
{
    if(consumer != null)
        consumer.shutdown();
    if(executor != null)
        executor.shutdown();
}

public void run(int numThreads)
{
    Map<String,Integer> topicCountMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(numThreads));
    Map<String,List<KafkaStream<byte[],byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[],byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
    int m=streams.size();

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

    int threadNumber=0;
    for(final KafkaStream stream : streams)
    {
        executor.submit(new ConsumerMsgTask(stream,threadNumber));
        threadNumber++;
    }
}

private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper,String a_groupId)
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
    props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "4000");
    props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

    return new ConsumerConfig(props);
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    String[] args = {"192.168.0.123:2181","group-a","test1","3"};
    String zooKeeper = args[0];
    String groupId = args[1];
    String topic = args[2];
    int threads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    ConsumerDemo demo = new ConsumerDemo(zooKeeper,groupId,topic);
    demo.run(threads);

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }catch (InterruptedException ie)
    {

    }
    demo.shutdown();

}
```

and this is ConsumerMsgTask

```
    public class ConsumerMsgTask implements Runnable {
private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> m_stream;
private int m_threadNumber;

public ConsumerMsgTask(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream,int threadNumber)
{
    m_threadNumber = threadNumber;
    m_stream = stream;
}

public void run()
{
    ConsumerIterator<byte[],byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
    int i=it.size();
    while(it.hasNext())
        System.out.println("Thread "+m_threadNumber+": "+ new String(it.next().message()));
     System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
}
```

and this is my ProducerDemo

```
    public class ProducerDemo {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rnd= new Random();
    int events=100;

    Properties props= new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.0.123:9092,192.168.0.123:9093,192.168.0.123:9094");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

    Producer<String,String> producer=new Producer<String,String>(config);
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<events;i++)
    {
        long runtime=new Date().getTime();
        String ip="192.168.5."+rnd.nextInt(255);
        String msgs=runtime+",www.maodou.com,"+ip;
        KeyedMessage<String,String> data=new KeyedMessage<String,String>("test1",ip,msgs);
        producer.send(data);
    }
    System.out.println("time："+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    producer.close();

}
```

}

I created the topic 'test1' by the command below

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.0.123:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic test1
```

This is using Kafka 0.8.2 running on CentOS release 6.5 (Final), 
using OpenJDK "1.7.0_45".

Comment: Did you try to consume from the command line? If not try this and tell me whether it has consumed any messages.                                         bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 192.168.0.123:2181 --topic test1 --from-beginning

Comment: I've tried and it consumed 100 messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do have the below code in your Main()? If so, removing it would solve the issue.
We hit the same issue as the main thread tries to shutdown the consumer after 10 seconds. You may have to implement gracefully shutting down/starting using Apache Commons Cli and Apache Commons Daemon.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {

}
example.shutdown();
```